# Four colour theorem in $3$ dimensions?

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs

There is, of course the 4 [colour theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem), which has been proven - every map can be coloured in just 4 colours.

However, has anything been examined in $3$ dimensions? By that, I mean how many different colours would I need to be able to colour in the parts of any cut up $3$D object?

Is it infinite, because any shape can have infinite sides?

Comment: Imagine a bowl of spaghetti where each noodle touches every other noodle.  There's no upper bound.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you take a set of square columns in the z=0 plane, such that there is a set for y=0, y=1, etc.  Now take a second set, turned at right angles and at z=1, so you have x=0, x=1, &c.  Now join these by pairs at x=n, y=n.

You now have an infinite number of X-shaped figures, each pair neighbouring another exactly twice (ie at i,j and j,i).

So there exists a construction fot infinite colours.

Comment: Surely you could colour that with less than infinite colours, just repeating them? Also, missing `)`.

Comment: Each piece touches every other piece, so no two can be the same color.

Comment: Even simpler construction: n spheres where every sphere is expanding by a pipe, making connection to the other. So we have construction with  n elements in 3-d world connected to each other.

Answer (score 6):

Image displays a theoretically infinite number of required colors

[image: Image displays a theoretically infinite number of required colors.]

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4):

There are meaningful generalizations, if you consider surfaces like sphere, torus, Möbius band etc. as "3D objects". The minimum number of required colors for the mentioned surfaces is 4, 7 and 6, respectively.